# How to specify a 10GB fixed size when creating a new Cosmos DB collection using the Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cli

I'm trying to figure out how to specify a 10GB fixed size when creating a new Cosmos DB collection using the Azure CLI.  The **az cosmosdb collection create** command does not let you specify that.  Must be right in my face but I can't see how can I achieve this.

```
az cosmosdb collection create --collection-name
                          --db-name
                          [--default-ttl]
                          [--indexing-policy]
                          [--key]
                          [--name]
                          [--partition-key-path]
                          [--resource-group-name]
                          [--throughput]
                          [--url-connection]
```

Doc link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cosmosdb/collection?view=azure-cli-latest#az-cosmosdb-collection-create

Comment: Just a hack: Can you try by specifying a throughput value of `400` (minimum throughput allowed for a fixed size collection)? You can then update the collection later and set its value to anywhere between 400 and 2500 (maximum throughput allowed for a fixed size collection).

Comment: Hey Gaurav!  Toan tried it and it creates a fixed size collection by default.  Looks like the command does not support creating the unlimited type.  I think the doc should be updated to reflect that.  I'll try to ping the team on Twitter to see what they have to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the CLI, you can create both fixed (10GB) and unlimited collections. The primary difference is whether you specify the partition key (and then specify throughput within the valid range for either fixed or unlimited collection). Partition key is required for unlimited collections.

For example, I just ran these two commands:

```
az cosmosdb collection create -d stackoverflow -c test1
--name <mycosmosaccountname> --key "<mycosmosaccountkey>"
--throughput 400

az cosmosdb collection create -d stackoverflow -c test2
--name <mycosmosaccountname> --key "<mycosmosaccountkey>"
--partition-key-path "/foo" --throughput 3000
```

This created both a 10GB collection and an unlimited collection:

[image: example of collections via cli]

Comment: Hey David!  Thanks for validating this.  I think that the doc should mention that.

Comment: @CSharpRocks - agreed, the docs could use a bit of refinement around this to clarify. I just looked, and saw there's no mention of fixed or unlimited collection, only mention of throughput (required) and partition key (optional).

Comment: This only creates fixed size collection with throughput < 10000 RUs. You cannot create a collection with 20000 RUs for example ( as at 24/07/2018).

Comment: @ToanNguyen This is not true. I literally just ran it. And created a 30000 RU collection. Please check and make sure you have the latest version of `az` installed. When you specify partition key, you may create an unlimited collection. Feel free to run it yourself with the syntax I included in my answer. If it doesn't run, then you probably have an older version of `az`.

Answer (score 0):

By default when you use the Azure CLI, the collection is created with a FIXED storage amout of 10Gb.

I ran this command

```
az cosmosdb collection create --collection-name "hither" --db-name "Lightning"  --name "toannsss"--db-name "Lightning" --resource-group-name "rsgroup" --name "toanns" --key "YourKey" --url-connection "https://toanns.documents.azure.com:443/"
```

Which created
[image]

I don't think there is an option to create unlimited size collection yet from Azure CLI as at 22/07/2018

Comment: Hi Toan!  Thanks for testing it, it's appreciated.

Comment: It is indeed possible; the difference is whether you specify a partition key (see my posted answer for more details and an example)

Comment: @DavidMakogon Can you create a collection with throughput > 10000 using CLI? I'm afraid not. Using UI you can create a collection with throughput > 10000

Comment: @ToanNguyen You absolutely can. I just tried it, just now, with CLI, and created one with 30000 RU. No issues. Just requires partition key path.

Comment: OK.I will give it ago.